# How to turn off (disable) SLUGGISH automatic intellisense checking with large nest loops when coding for Java

Tags: netbeans

I simply typed-in 28 nested loops into NetBeans for Java, and netbeans keeps auto-scanning the code, making it very sluggish.

My code is basically empty. I only just setup the 28 for...loop conditions with nothing else inside the loops yet.

But netbeans pauses my cursor... does some sort of auto intellisense thinking for 3 seconds... then gives me control over my cursor for about 1 second before pausing to "think" again.

Is there a way to stop netbeans from automatically losing itself in these automatic, auto-scanning processes? (and I'm NOT talking about during compile/run... I mean, netbeans is sluggish during editing).

Which option can I turn off inside of netbeans to allow me to edit without having to wait for 3 seconds every 1 second?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After turning off several options & attempting to place older modules in the netbeans folder (as per [NetBeans background scanning projects takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811246/netbeans-background-scanning-projects-takes-too-long)) for this version (8.0.2), dumping it altogether and moving to 7.4 fixed this problem (AND, the occasional automatic project file, 'scan' of death)